# If Neural Networks are lowsy interpolators then why do we use them alot? Are there better alternatives?

Tags: approximation, neural-networks

So Neural Nets (NN) are [universal function approximators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) and currently being exploited a lot in various applications to learn underlying function that explains some behaviors, so my question is ,this post claims that neural nets are [lousy interpolators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797529/is-function-evaluation-by-neural-net-faster-then-the-analytical-expression-for-t?noredirect=1#comment7824057_3797529) and they are not as fast as if we directly program the generic function they aim to approximate, then why are they being used abundantly? Are there better alternatives to neural nets as superior universal approximators or can we work out the actual analytical form of the behaviour that we no longer need NN's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use neural networks for tasks where we don't know what to do, and can get a neural network to do it by saying "here, look at these examples, and do that, but more generally". You are exactly right that if we can work out a formula for the behavior we want, then we'd usually do better by implementing the formula than by using a neural network.

The tradeoff is:

- If there is a *fast*, *exact* method for solving the problem (such as in the examples you give in the other question, where we want to find $\sin x$), then there's basically no chance for neural networks to be useful.
- If there is an *exact but slow* method, then it's possible that you could train a neural network to give faster, approximate answers.
- However, if there are known *fast approximation algorithms*, then they'll usually be a better choice. In particular, we can often prove that an approximation algorithm will have some guaranteed performance - and it is very hard to make guarantees about the output of a neural network.

The most interesting applications of neural networks are to things like image recognition where we expect that there's some nice underlying pattern to what cats look like (or whatever), so there's some hope that the neural network will learn to approximate that pattern, but we don't have any mathematical description of it.

Comment: I do have bunch of followup questions to conclude the thought: 1. what did you mean by "so there's some hope that the neural network will learn to approximate that pattern" are you suggesting we dont have any formal gurantees whether NN will approximate the underlying entity in your example what cats look like? So we apply NN to those things whose concrete formulations dont exist (we cant necessarily formulate a generic equation of how a cat looks like) and hope they work well. In that case what did author in the linked post meant by lousy interpolators? As per my knowledge NN perform ...

Comment: .. good interpolation especially with images - GAN's and in some cases even fool human! So are they really lousy interpolators?

Comment: (1) Right, we don't have guarantees about whether NNs will work. Approximation theorems for NNs generally only guarantee that there *is* some NN that approximates a given function, not that you'll be able to find it (that is, train a NN to do that).

Comment: (2) There's two "regimes" of interpolation: one where you're given lots and lots of information (relative to the dimension of the input space), and one where you're given very little information. A neural network often does very well in the second case - if there's actually some reasonable fit to the data, the NN will find it. But the neural network doesn't start performing *much* better in the first case, whereas the other techniques with lookup tables now become feasible, and perform better.

Comment: (In particular, when working with images, you're usually in the second regime, since there's lots and lots and lots of possible images, and you're given information about only a tiny fraction of them.)

Comment: Ok, this makes so much sense now. So to sum up your last two comments, neural nets usually pefrom better in the second case where we are given "very little" information while LUT perform better in the first case where we are given lots of information. Right? I can imagine the size for that LUT must be quite large to encode all the stuff given in the data!

Comment: The size of the lookup table would be very large, but neural networks aren't magic either; if you wanted your NN to fit all the data exactly, it would have to be as large as the lookup table.